# Find the corresponding units dimensional analysis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis

> Consider $[x] = L, [m] = M, [t] = T$,
>
> $$ m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \alpha x + \beta x^3 = F_0\sin(\omega t)$$
>
> On the RHS $F_0, \omega$ are also unknown units.
>
> Calculate the dimensions of $\alpha$.

$$\frac{ML}{T^2} + [\alpha]\cdot L + [\beta]\cdot L^3 = [F_0]\sin(\omega t)$$

I know we can't add units of different units, so how can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the terms in your sum should have the same unit.

Consequently $[\alpha]=\dfrac{M}{T^2}$, and I think you can infer the other ones following this example.

Besides, $\sin(\omega t)$ does not have any unit, therefore you can remove it from your last equation. This shows that $[F_0]$ has the same unit as $[\alpha]L$.

Comment: So $F_0 = ML/T^2$?

Comment: yes, and since $F_0$ seems to be a force it is correct